# How to register as versioned using SDELayer?

Tags: postgresql, enterprise-geodatabase, versioning, command-line, sdelayer

This is the normal process using ArcCatalog :

[image]

I want to automate this process using sdeLayer or any tools - does anybody have an idea as to how to do it?

**there is an application sdelayer (sdelayer.exe) in "C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\ArcSDE\pgexe\bin" i want to create a command line to register featurelayer**

```
sdelayer -o register -l <table,column> -e <entity_mask> -t <storage_type>
{[-C <row_id_column>[,{SDE|USER}[,<min_ID>]]]} [Spatial_Index]
[-E <{empty | xmin,ymin,xmax,ymax}>] [{-R <SRID> | [Spatial_Ref_Opts]}]
[-S <layer_description_str>] [-k <config_keyword>]
[-i {<service> | <port#> | <direct connection>}] [-s <server_name>]
[-D <database_name>] -u <DB_user_name> [-p <DB_user_password>] [-q]
```

Comment: database name : sde 
user          : mr
password      : test 
feature layer name : parcel
parcel column geometry : shape 
port postges      : 5433
user PostgreSQL/arcsde     : postgres
password PostgreSQL/arcsde : test2 
server                   : localhost

Comment: i want to know that why registering as versioned is necessary. Because if it helps to track a record of delete and add ( Delta Tables), then what is the function of checking or uncheking the option of " Moving the edits into a base table"...?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You got the wrong `sde*` command. `sdelayer` is for the spatial data in a SDE table. The `sdetable` column is for working on the table, such as adding/removing columns, adding indexes, etc.

You can register a table for SDE with something like this:

> sdetable -o register -t railroads -i 5151 -u scott -p tiger -s localhost

When you want to have it versioned in the *normal* way, use the -V switch:

> sdetable -o register -t railroads [...] -V MULTI

And when you want to **move edits to base**, use `hybrid`:

> sdetable -o register -t railroads [...] **-V HYBRID**

My table has a column ID, and it needs to be the OBJECTID column, so I specify:

> sdetable -o register -t railroads [...] -V HYBRID **-C sde -c ID**

Answer (score 2):

Try using [Register As Versioned (Data Management)](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//0017000000pm000000) GP tool. This GP tool can be used in a Python script:

```
import arcpy
sde_workspace = r"C:\databasegeo.sde" #path to your .sde file connection on disk
fcs_list = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()
for fc in fcs_list:
    arcpy.RegisterAsVersioned_management(fc, "EDITS_TO_BASE")
```

Comment: please @Alex do you know how to do it with VB.net ?

Dim toolR As ESRI.ArcGIS.DataManagementTools.RegisterAsVersioned = New ESRI.ArcGIS.DataManagementTools.RegisterAsVersioned

Comment: @AbdelMounaimTAOUSSI, do you want to use the GP tool in your VB code? I guess you could just use ISQLSyntax to get the name of the owner and IVersionedObject to register a featureclass (and other household work) as versioned. http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/RegisterAsVersioned_Method/002500000m1v000000/. Unfortunately, cannot provide any specific details since I don't work with VB that much.

Comment: there is an application sdelayer (sdelayer.exe) in "C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\ArcSDE\pgexe\bin" i want to create a command line to register featurelayer

Comment: You cannot register a feature class/table as versioned by using ArcSDE Commands. They are not aware of geodatabase behaviour. You need to use GP tool/Python/ArcObjects. sdelayer.exe has register option which is for registering the table with SDE, not to register as versioned.

Comment: thank you  @Alex Tereshenkov, i have 10 featureclasses and i'm working with arcgis engine (vb.net) i think with  Gp tool i can only register feature classes  one by one 
-->this is my problem : i want to export DB as  XML  and import it , when i import all feature-classes i have to register them

Comment: I bet you can use IVersionedObject in ArcObjects to iterate through multiple feature classes. If not, then use Python or ModelBuilder (it has Iterate Feature Classes iterator).

Answer (score 0):

solved (thank you @Alex ) so this is a sample code that i used to register one feature class so after that we can iterate feature class to register them:

```
   Public featureLayer1 As IFeatureLayer = New FeatureLayerClass
   featureLayer1.FeatureClass = featureWorkspace.OpenFeatureClass("parcels")
   Dim pVersionedObject As IVersionedObject

   pVersionedObject = featureLayer1.FeatureClass

     'Determining if the feature class is registered as versioned
     If pVersionedObject.IsRegisteredAsVersioned = False Then
        'regester feature as versionned 
        pVersionedObject.RegisterAsVersioned(True)
     End If
```